# rails accept nested atributes for a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I have an error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Upload", but I have assigned it to be accessible.

This is a nested form with a polymorphic association.

Models

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :link, :post_id
  belongs_to :uploadable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :uploads_attributes
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? 
  }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I tried too put accept_nested ... for :uploadable but tells me dont exist the association

The action new on the controller is this one

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.uploads.new
end
```

and here is the form for create

```
<%= form_for [:admin,@post], remote: true, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description%><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :upload do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'upload_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Upload", f, :uploads %>  
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The partial ...

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :file %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Dont think the javascript affects, so Im not going to put it here.
How I cna solve "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" on polymorphic asociations ?

Plz need help on this anyone. Cant belive I cant upload files, looks so simple on tutorials, and Its not working, or I get a Can't mass assign orthe upload its not saved ....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@post.uploads.build` instead of `@post.uploads.new`

Answer (score 0):

The associated model needs to know the identity of her parent to save the relationship.
I recommend you the following railscast: [Polymorphic Association.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

```
#uploads_controller.rb
before_filter :load_uploadable

def create
  @upload = @uploadable.uploads.new(params[:upload])
....
end

private

def load_uploadable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2] # /posts/1
  @uploadable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This line inside your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :upload do |builder| %>
```

Should be this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploadable do |builder| %>
```

Because the association on the `Post` model is called "uploadable", not "upload".

For nested attributes to work, you will need to specify the model does accept nested attributes for this model, which can be done by putting this line underneath the `belongs_to` in your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploadable
```

And then you will need to make these attributes accessible, which you can do with this:

```
attr_accessible :uploadable_attributes
```

Comment: If I put accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploadable in the model Post, tells me -> No association found for name `uploadable'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: more info on the error => ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::PostsController#create

Comment: note too if I use this on the upload controller --   @post = @post.uploads.new i got this error undefined method `admin_uploads_path'